# How to parse Soap XML(Dataset) in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xml-serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse XML (DataSet) in Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669817/how-to-parse-xml-dataset-in-windows-phone-7)

I have a XML Like Below, But i am not able to parse it. Please help me to parse the below XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope     
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"     
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body>
<GetResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetResult>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<aaa>hi1</aaa>
<bbb>hi2</bbb>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
<aaa>hi3</aaa>
<bbb>hi4</bbb>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</GetResponse></GetResult>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here i want the results of the Table (i.e a,b ) tag. I tried using Linq but i am not able parse it. i tried the code some thing like this:

```
String response = e.response;
public static String myNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/";
XDocument reader = XDocument.Parse(response);
XElement resultElement = reader.Descendants(XName.Get("GetResult", myNamespace)).Single(); 
XElement resultNewDataSet= resultElement.Descendants(XName.Get("NewDataSet", "")).Single();
```

So now in resultNewDataSet i got XML Like Below:

```
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
  <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<aaa>hi1</aaa>
<bbb>hi2</bbb>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<aaa>hi3</aaa>
<bbb>hi4</bbb>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

So Now how can i find the values of aaa tag and bbb tag ?

Thanks in advance.